# What does this Ruby Regex mean?

Tags: ruby, regex

```
if (banners = /Ability Server 2\\.34g/)
```

I am just getting confused of this regex expression in Ruby. What does this regex expression talking of? what does `g/` mean?

I am thinking I am somehow mistaken about regex expression in Ruby, because I am not supposed to be confused of this simple issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using regex to test string, you need to use `=~` instead of `=`.

```
if (banners =~ /Ability Server 2\.34g/)
```

And the `g` in your regex is just a `g`, you are testing if a string contains the string `'Ability Server 2.34g'`